# empty set intersection of two sets disjoint

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Assume $\;P(A\cap B) = 0\;,\;$ is it true that then $A\cap B =\emptyset\;$?
If $P(A∩B)=0$, then the two events A and B are mutually exclusive or disjoint events because they cannot occur at the same time. Therefore, $A\cap B =\emptyset\;$.  However I was wondering if there is more to this?  Could I relate this to area?

Comment: It's not true. Let $U$ be a uniform $(0, 1)$ random variable. Let $A = B = \{U = 0.5\}$. We have $P(U = 0.5) = 0$, but $\{U = 0.5\} \neq \emptyset$. Actually $P(U = x) = 0$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$.